# Haskell: How to put multiple instances in the same module?

Tags: haskell

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
import Data.List.Ordered

data Person = Person String String
     deriving (Show, Eq)

main :: IO ()
main = print . show . sort $ [(Person "Isaac" "Newton"), (Person "Johannes" "Kepler")]
```

And in the same module, I want to be able to sort the list by both first name and by last name.  Obviously I can't do this:

```
instance Ord Person where
         compare (Person _ xLast) (Person _ yLast) = compare xLast yLast

instance Ord Person where
         compare (Person xFirst _) (Person yFirst _) = compare xFirst yFirst
```

So, what are my options?

[This page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Multiple_instances) mentions "You can achieve this by wrapping the type in a newtype and lift all required instances to that new type."  Can someone give an example of that?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Minor note: the output is a little easier to read if you do `print . sort` instead of `print . show . sort`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The newtype method would be:

```
newtype ByFirstname = ByFirstname { unByFirstname :: Person }

instance Ord ByFirstname where
  -- pattern matching on (ByFirstname (Person xFirst _)) etc
  compare [...] = [...]

newtype ByLastname = ByLastname { unByLastname :: Person }

instance Ord ByLastname where
  -- as above
```

Then the sorting function would be something like:

```
sortFirstname = map unByFirstname . sort . map ByFirstname
```

and similarly for `ByLastname`.

---

A better way is to use `sortBy`, `compare` and `on`, with functions for retrieving the first and last names. i.e.

```
sortFirstname = sortBy (compare `on` firstName)
```

(On that note, it might be worth using a record type for `Person`, i.e. `data Person = Person { firstName :: String, lastName :: String }`, and one even gets the accessor functions for free.)

Answer (score 9):

You don't want to define multiple `Ord` instances just to sort by different orders.  You just need to use the `sortBy` function, which takes an explicit comparison function as its argument.

Neat trick: if you use record types to define your `Person` type, import `Data.Function` (which gives you the `on` function) and `Data.Monoid`, you can use some neat tricks to make this much briefer and easy:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Monoid (mappend)
import Data.List (sortBy)

data Person = Person { firstName :: String, lastName :: String }

instance Show Person where
    show p = firstName p ++ " " ++ lastName p

exampleData = [ Person "Mary" "Smith"
              , Person "Joe" "Smith"
              , Person "Anuq" "Katig"
              , Person "Estanislao" "Martínez"
              , Person "Barack" "Obama" ]
-- 
-- The "on" function allows you to construct comparison functions out of field
-- accessors:
--
--     compare `on` firstName :: Person -> Person -> Ordering
--     
-- That expression evaluates to something equivalent to this:
--
--    (\x y -> compare (firstName x) (firstName y))
--
sortedByFirstName = sortBy (compare `on` firstName) exampleData
sortedByLastName = sortBy (compare `on` lastName) exampleData

--
-- The "mappend" function allows you to combine comparison functions into a
-- composite one.  In this one, the comparison function sorts first by lastName,
-- then by firstName:
--
sortedByLastNameThenFirstName = sortBy lastNameFirstName exampleData
    where lastNameFirstName = 
              (compare `on` lastName) `mappend` (compare `on` firstName)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason that page mentions `newtype` is that you cannot have two instances of the same class for a given type.  Well, you *can* but not in the same scope and it's generally a really bad idea.  See [Orphan Instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) for more information (as C. A. McCann pointed out this isn't about orphan instances.  I included the link because it has a good description of why duplicate instances, even in cases that superficially work, is a bad idea.).

An example of `newtype` would be:

```
newtype SortFirst = SF Person

instance Ord Person where
         compare (Person _ xLast) (Person _ yLast) = compare xLast yLast

instance Ord SortFirst where
         compare (SF (Person xFirst _)) (SF (Person yFirst _)) = compare xFirst yFirst
```

Then when you want to sort by first name you would have to do:

```
sort (map SF persons)
```

It's not very convenient so it may be better to use `sortBy` which takes an comparison function as an argument.

Comment: Orphan instances are merely a matter of where the definition is located. I don't believe conflicting instances are ever allowed, essentially because there's no such thing as "scope" for instances--they're instantly and unavoidably contagious, even from modules that export nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, it's not specifically about orphan instances but that page has a good explanation of how instances are exported (always) and why that makes declaring duplicate instances anywhere very dangerous.  It seemed like good information to include given that the code in question would work if separated into different modules and never simultaneously imported.  The page explains why doing things like that is a bad idea in general.  I'll edit the answer to indicate that.

Comment: Yes, a fair point. It's mostly the term "scope" that bothered me, since that usually implies something smaller than "the entire program", heh. But it is good to be aware that the only way to settle conflicting instances between two modules amounts to "pistols at dawn".

Comment: It's my understanding that the scope is "the module declaring the instance and anywhere that module is imported" which is a bit more subtle than the entire program.  Quoting from the linked article " If you want to use multiple instances for the same class/type, you have to ensure that they are never imported together in a module somewhen."  I've never actually tested this though, is it actually not possible to _use_ two modules declaring duplicate instances anywhere in the same program?

Comment: That's what I meant by instances being "unavoidably contagious". Consider two libraries, each of which define an instance of class C for type T. Both instances are in internal modules not exposed by the package but imported by public modules, and neither package re-exports either C or T as part of its public API. Using both libraries in one program will, I believe, result in both instances being imported by the main module, which is an error even if neither C or T is imported from anywhere.

Comment: Okay, actually wrote the code to see how it works :)  The short version is, you have to jump through some hoops but you can use duplicate class instances in the same program.  [Here's the code on github](https://github.com/asmyers/instances-test).  For anyone else that runs across this, that code is an example of something that *should never be done in a real program*.

Comment: Oh, interesting--I would not have expected that to work. I'll have to take a closer look later.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that all the functions in `Data.List.Ordered` have "by" variants that let you provide a comparison function rather than using an `Ord` instance. If there's no single obvious "standard" ordering, that's not a bad option.

It then becomes your responsibility to ensure any given list is always used with a consistent comparison function, however, which is a potential source of all *kinds* of fun bugs.

If I needed to work with many ordered lists using a variety of orderings, rather than fussing with `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping--which is dreadfully tedious--I'd consider a data type to bundle a list with its comparison function, then define proxy functions that use the "by" functions with the associated comparison.

Comment: I think that's that what the newtype + Ord instance does, except that the compiler keeps the comparison function in a datatype dictionary rather than passing it around explicitly. I remember the joy when we switched a project from Orwell to Gofer and stopped passing around equality functions explicitly: it was fabulously cleaner.

Comment: @AndrewC: Essentially, yes. The trade-off is that instances are unavoidably global and implicit, which is great for `Eq` or `Functor`, but not so much when there are many useful instances. `newtype` wrappers are a monstrous irritation in cases like this, because you often have lots of functions on the underlying type that you want to use at the same time.

Comment: What I mean is that the wrapping and unwrapping of a newtype is no more tedious than wrapping and unwrapping of a `data` declaration, but I realise now I didn't read carefully enough, and you meant the list, sorry. Sometimes it's OK to let the user choose what to sort by at runtime so you can use the `sortBy` and friends freely and safely, but I agree there are times when you need to be clear about _the_ way to sort given data.

Comment: Ah, yes--packing a class dictionary together with the "instance" type gains nothing in that regard (though it has certain other uses). This is more along the lines of stashing a private `Ord` instance inside of a `Data.Set`.

Comment: The `newtype` package removes some of the tedium.  Another under-used option is GHC's implicit parameter support (which is essentially the same as `*By` functions).  Those aside, I agree  100% with this comment.  Implicit class dictionaries are fabulous until there's >1 useful variant.

Comment: @JohnL: Yes, and I have a collection of infix `newtype` combinators lying around somewhere. It does indeed soothe the pain a bit, but at some point it's time to accept that shoving one's hand into a meat grinder is not a problem to solve with painkillers. As for implicit parameters, they don't seem to be popular except as a means for generating interesting error messages, which inclines me to suspect that their under-use is due to being, in actual practice, under-useful.

Comment: @C.A.McCann - I think implicit parameters are under-used due to a chicken-and-egg problem.  Also, they seem isomorphic to providing another argument, without requiring YALP.  And they're missing the consistency of type classes (try writing e.g. Data.Set with implicit params).  So I agree they're of limited utility except for very specific situations, and they've never achieved enough uptake to even be popular when they are useful.

Comment: @JohnL: Yeah, and it's quite likely I'd not recognize such a situation if one came up in practice. On the other hand, using implicit parameters to generate error messages that tell you what type fits into a hole in an expression is surprisingly handy!